# What type is the first parameter of a command invoced from the file explorer in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When invoking a command from a context menu in the file explorer:

```
let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('my-extension.my-command', (...args) => {
        console.log(args);
    });
```

Results in:

```
(2) [w, Array(0)]
 > 0: w {scheme: "file", authority: "", path: "some/path", query:"", fragment: "", ...}
 > (1) [w]
```

What type is "w"? If I want to access any parameters like path, Typescript wants me to specify the type of the argument. What type is it? I can for the life of me not find any documentation about this in the official API and guides.

Answer (score 0):

After comparing the attributes of the parameter with other objects I concluded it has to be:

`vscode.Uri`